# how to join mp3 in linux machine using php

Tags: php, linux, mp3

I have this mp3 folder that contains mp3 generate from Google Text To Speech (TTS).

[image]

**I using WinSCP to access the webserver which is using Linux.**

Since the **number of mp3 in this folder is not fix**, i cant use this command to join the mp3 via php script.

```
cat file1.mp3 file2.mp3 > new_file1.mp3
```

This command works but it join the mp3 without the correct order.

```
cat *.mp3 > new_filename.mp3
```

Question is how to join the mp3 based on the date time it created? Or if i rename all the mp3 into 1.mp3 etc filename, i want it to be join based on the filename ascending.

Comment: This is a little confusing because that screenshot is definitely windows :)

Comment: i am using WinSCP to access the webserver which is using Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -t | xargs cat > new_filename.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FFMPEG or php (I'm not familar with php)?

http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/download.html

FFMPEG will do the job, here is the command to concatenate files:

cat output1.mpg output2.mpg output3.mpg > outputall.mpg

Comment: hi the problem is i cannot enter the filename manually since the number of mp3 in that folder is depends on the output generated by Google TTS.

Answer (score 0):

You have `sth.mp3` `sth.mp3` `sth.mp3` ... ok?

(time based: )

`ls -lt | grep -i mp3 | awk '{ print $8}' | xargs > x cat`

(time based (Reversed )

`ls -ltr | grep -i mp3 | awk '{ print $8}' | xargs > x cat`